# Dojo 1.7 eclipse error

Tags: java, eclipse, dojo

I am a Java developer and i am using Dojo with spring framework and i am usign eclipse for developement purpose. Till Dojo 1.6.1 everything was fine but after updating dojo to 1.7.1  i am facing error in eclipse.
Please let me know what could be the issue and what i can do to resolve this error?

**Eclipse version** - Indigo 
**Error Description :**Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'JavaScript Validator' on project 'abc project'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

**File with error**:  "svg2gfx.xsl"

Even if i delete the given file i will face the same error for some othe js file and it keeps coming

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Building on @missingno's answer, you should not only turn off validation for the dojo-releated files, (javascript validator, as well as xsl validator), but you can set the dojo related folders as `derived`.  This basically tells eclipse that these files are not a part of your source (even if they are under source control).  You can do this by right clicking on a folder and checking the `Derived` checkbox under attributes.  This way eclipse will better behave around the dojo files.

Answer (score 1):

My bet from the error message is that Eclipse is trying to validate the XSL files as if they were Javascript and is thus getting confused. I did a quick search and apparently there are ways to disable the validator, either globally or just for the troublesome files.